# Re-Entry in Italy (lost residence permit before leaving italy - permesso di soggiorno)

Tags: customs-and-immigration, italy, pakistani-citizens, residency, lost-documents

I had a flight for my home country (Pakistan) in last days. On the day of departure, while going to airport, I lost all my documents including passport and permesso di soggiorno. I filed a loss report with airport police. As I need to visit my country for some special reason, therefore, police advised me to get temporary travel document from my consulate and leave Italy.

Now, what are the possible ways to fly back to Italy. And, what would be the requirements for it. Is it hard to get it or not a big deal. It may be further noted that the documents are lost in Italy and Police report is also issued here. Also, the lost (valid) permesso was expiring after 2 months and few days. I wanted to come back before its expiry on the planned travel.

I would appreciate comments from people passed through similar scenarios or have know-how about that. I hold copies of all my documents.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a copy of a residence Permit (valid or expired), you can re-enter Italy if you also have a confirmation from the post Office **or** the Police stating that you've applied for a new residence Permit.

If you hold a copy of an expired Permit, you Need a confirmation from the Police stating that it's a legitimate copy

So, reading your question, it should be possible. What could be a Problem is convincing the Airline to let you board. Although they can look up the correct info, my experience is they're often too lazy to.